# Function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist on Knex pg

Tags: postgresql, uuid, knex.js

I have a pg database with the following extension: **uuid-ossp**.
Creating a table using `uuid_generate_v4()` as default value fails.

```
await db.raw(`CREATE DATABASE 'test'`);

await db.raw(`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";`);

await db.raw(`
  -- test.audit definition

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS audit (
    audit_id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (audit_id)
  );
`);
```

Error: - **function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist**

Database exist and the extension is installed since tring with another client it works.

Comment: If you are using Postgres 13 or later, you don't need the extension any more. There is now a built-in function [gen_random_uuid()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html)

Comment: After `create database` you need to _connect_ to that database, otherwise all following SQL statements will be run against the database you initially connected to. In your case the create extension is **not** run in the database `test`.

Comment: Btw: having a create database in a migration script is typically not a good idea. Databases should be created and managed by the DBA (through the superuser). The application user should not have the privileges to create databases or extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Await wasn't worked as expected so I've add a callback to add exstention only when db is created properly.

```
await db.raw(`CREATE DATABASE ${database}`).then(
  await db.raw(`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";`)
);
```

This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

await knex.raw('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";')